# How to get the value of a local variable in C++?

Tags: c++, local-variables

I've always struggled with getting local variables from selection structures. I'm new to programming in general, and I need help with calculating the total purchase of items where their values are inside `if` functions, and I'm having trouble with my `while` function, because I intend to use the it to infinitely accept meal code and quantity until the user enters `0`, but it doesn't work. How do I make my infinite `while` function work, and how do I properly get the values from selection structures? Any help, tips, and suggestions are appreciated!

Update: I was able to fix my problem with variables inside functions. Current problem is that I need to type in `0` twice because the first `0` gets ignored, and I don't know why.

```
int main()
{
    char mealCode;
    bool noOrder = false;
    int quantity = -1, subTotalA = 0, subTotalB = 0, subTotalC = 0, subTotalD = 0, subTotalE = 0, total = 0;

while (quantity != 0)
{
    cin >> mealCode >> quantity;
    if (quantity == 0)
        break;
    else
    {
        if (mealCode == 'A')
        {
            subTotalA += 45 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalA << endl;
        }
        else if (mealCode == 'B')
        {
            subTotalB += 50 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalB << endl;
        }
        else if (mealCode == 'C')
        {
            subTotalC += 55 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalC << endl;
        }
        else if (mealCode == 'D')
        {
            subTotalD += 60 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalD << endl;
        }
        else if (mealCode == 'E')
        {
            subTotalE += 75 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalE << endl;
        }
    }
    total = subTotalA + subTotalB + subTotalC + subTotalD + subTotalE;
    cout << "Total Purchase is" << total;
}
```

}

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not well problem description.

Comment: Two things I see in your code. 1. Most of your code isn't actually in the `while` loop. You would want all those `if` statements go inside your `while` loop. 2. You never accumulated your total. You would want to add your total by `total = total + subTotalA + ...` or better `total += subTotalA + ....` Even better, you never actually needed the subtotals. Instead in all the `if` statements, you could have something like `cout << 50 * quantity` and `total += 50 * quantity`.

Comment: @S.M. I could not find a better way to describe that it doesn't work, because technically nothing was happening when I was testing it.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep I updated my code and included my statements inside the loop. I have to keep sub totals for now to print them out because my program is supposed to print out the subtotal of each meal, then calculate and print out the total purchase of all meals.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `while` loop to be infinite until quantity equal 0, you need to write it so. You don't need two identical `cin`.

Also it's better to use `switch` control structure if you are going to compare with so many constants that way.

For example, you may want to do something like this:

```
char mealCode;
int quantity = -1;

while (quantity != 0)
{
    cin >> mealCode >> quantity;
    if(quantity == 0)
    {
        break;
    }

    switch(mealCode)
    {
        case 'A':
            subTotalA = 45 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalA << endl;
            break;

        case 'B':
        // ...

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see! That makes sense to have an assigned quantity for the while loop. I tried making the switch function exactly like how you showed the example, but that will not make me calculate the total purchase of each mean since the value is inside the switch function. How do I get around that?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want to do, but a couple of comments

- if you want to keep track of the subtotals and totals you need to initialize the variables to 0 and then sum the new subtotals for each product
- If you want to use more than one product you need to include the operations in the while loop (while the user keeps introducing meals with a quantity!=0 you keep computing the subtotals)

Something like

```
    char mealCode;
    int subTotalA=0, subTotalB=0, total,quantity;

   
    while (cin >> mealCode >> quantity)
    {
        if (quantity <= 0) { break; }

        if (mealCode == 'A')
        {
            subTotalA += 45 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalA << endl;
        }
        if (mealCode == 'B')
        {
            subTotalB += 50 * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotalB << endl;
        }
      
        total = subTotalA + subTotalB ;
        cout << "Total Purchase is Php" << total;
    }
```

Comment: should be `while (cin >> mealCode >> quantity)` because you want to exit when the read fails

Comment: yes @M.M,  and then a break in case the value (which we already know is an int) is ```quantity<=0``` I change it in the reply

Comment: I tried initializing my subTotal and total, and it works just as intended now. Only problem I have is that I have to type in 0 twice because the first 0 gets ignored. I don't know why that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I dislike the `if` and `switch` solutions, so let's play with this a bit and eliminate the duplication.

```cpp
#include <iostream> //cin. cout
#include <cstring> //strchr
#include <numeric> //std::accumulate
#include <iterator> //std::begin and std::end
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char mealCode;
    int quantity;

    // use tables to replace the different code for different meal codes
    // list valid meal codes
    const char mealCodes[] = "ABCDE";
    // list cost of each meal code.
    const int mealCosts[] = {45, 50, 55, 60, 75};

    // Sucks when you ass an item to one table and not the other
    // so lets give ourselves a reminder, hmmm?
    // Refuse to compile if the costs and codes don't line up
    // note the -1 to ignore the null terminator in the string
    static_assert(std::size(mealCodes) - 1 == std::size(mealCosts),
                  "Meal codes and meal costs aren't the same size");

    // when you have a bunch of sequentially numbered variables that's nature
    // telling you you want an array. This one is forced to be the same size
    // as the number of meal codes. They're all 0, so no magic is required.
   int subTotal[std::size(mealCodes)] = {0};

    while (cin >> mealCode >> quantity && quantity != 0) // loop until bad input
                                                         // or quantity 0
    {
        // verify meal code
        const char * found = strchr(mealCodes, mealCode);
        if (found) // found a valid meal code
        {
            //get index of mealCode in mealCodes
            size_t index = found - mealCodes;
            // Look up the cost in the table and accumulate
            subTotal[index] += mealCosts[index] * quantity;
            // not 100% sure about the += but not summing multiple 
            // runs of the same meal code run seems wrong

            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotal[index] << endl;
        }
    }
    // sum up all of the subtotals
    int total = std::accumulate(std::begin(subTotal), std::end(subTotal), 0);
    cout << "Total Purchase is Php" << total;
}
```

Advantages: adding a new meal code is two changes in the code: Add the code to `mealCodes` and add the cost to `mealCosts`.

Without the gratuitous comments the program is pretty short and isn't getting much bigger as the number of meals grows.

```cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstring> 
#include <numeric> 
#include <iterator> 
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char mealCode;
    int quantity;

    const char mealCodes[] = "ABCDEFGHIJK";
    const int mealCosts[] = {45, 50, 55, 60, 75, 13, 62, 88, 42, 10, 99 };
    static_assert(std::size(mealCodes) - 1 == std::size(mealCosts),
                  "Meal codes and meal costs aren't the same size");
   int subTotal[std::size(mealCodes)] = {0};

    while (cin >> mealCode >> quantity && quantity != 0) 
    {
        const char * found = strchr(mealCodes, mealCode);
        if (found)
        {
            size_t index = found - mealCodes;
            subTotal[index] += mealCosts[index] * quantity;
            cout << "Subtotal is " << subTotal[index] << endl;
        }
    }
    int total = std::accumulate(std::begin(subTotal), std::end(subTotal), 0);
    cout << "Total Purchase is Php" << total;
}
```